# Mobile SDK Hybrid Template - How do I change splash screen?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I am looking at the AccountEditor sample and although I have added a new splash screen image in my project, It is not refelecting on iPad. It works fine on iPhone though.

What could be reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's visible on iPhone but not on iPad, it probably means you changed only the Default.png file

There are other iPad specific files that you need to change

768 x 1004 pixels

```
Default-Portrait.png
```

1024 x 748 pixels

```
Default-Landscape.png
```

Retina1536 x 2008 pixels

```
Default-Portrait@2x.png
```

2048 x 1496 pixels

```
Default-Landscape@2x.png
```

Change these and it should be relfected on your iPad as well.